# Why is my textFieldDidEndEditing tag not working?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tags, uitextfield

Good day!

I have a `UITableView` and **two cells** with its corresponding `UITextField`. I created the **UITextField** via **for loop**:

```
- (UITextField *)createInformationTextField:(NSString *)createInformationTextField createInformationPlaceholder:(NSString *)createInformationPlaceholder
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        informationTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 170, 30)];

        informationTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        informationTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        informationTextField.placeholder = createInformationPlaceholder;
        informationTextField.text = createInformationTextField;
        informationTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        informationTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        informationTextField.tag = i;
    }

    return informationTextField;
}
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *name;
    NSString *address;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    informationTextField = [self createInformationTextField:name createInformationPlaceholder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", informationTextField.tag]];

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
                    [cell addSubview:informationTextField];
                    break;

                case 1:
                    informationTextField = [self createInformationTextField:address createInformationPlaceholder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", informationTextField.tag]];

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Address";
                    [cell addSubview:informationTextField];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            break;

        case 1:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"State";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    informationTextField.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

I set the `UITableView` **placeholder** to display its corresponding **tag**, and its working fine.

Screenshot:

[image]

The problem is in my `textFieldDidEndEditing`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"Name Field. The tag is %d", textField.tag);
            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Address Field. The tag is %d", textField.tag);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried to output its **tag** again **after** a user inputs something in the `UITextField`, but this is what I see

```
2013-06-06 17:36:53.050 UITableUITextField[20387:c07] Address Field. The tag is 1
2013-06-06 17:36:55.636 UITableUITextField[20387:c07] Address Field. The tag is 1
```

[Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html)

Comment: can u pls post ur code to add textfield

Comment: @manujmv inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling **createInformationTextField** method to create textfield. I think you are invoking this method from each cell. So when you are calling this method, it enters to the for loop, and after two loops, it return the textfield with tag 1 returns for every cell. thats why you are getting tag 1 for every textfield. Try to call the below method from your *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* method

```
 - (UITextField *)createInformationTextField:(NSString *)createInformationTextField createInformationPlaceholder:(NSString *)createInformationPlaceholder index:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    {

        UITextField *informationTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 170, 30)];

        informationTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        informationTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        informationTextField.placeholder = createInformationPlaceholder;
        informationTextField.text = createInformationTextField;
        informationTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        informationTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        informationTextField.tag = indexPath.row;

        return informationTextField;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set your tag to your text field in your for loop like this.

```
nameTxtFld.tag = 0;
addressTxtFld.tag = 1;
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your very quick reply. I modified the question above, and added my **for loop** statement. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Uhm, may I ask where? And/or maybe a solution too?

Comment: i tried you code is correct i think may be problem outside this code.